# How do i fade out all the other tr tags with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I want the user to click on the checkbox and other tr tags fade out and disappear...

Here is the code for the table

```
<table class="display" id="events" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


<tbody>
    <tr class="gradeA odd">

        <td><input id="instance_selected0" name="instance_selected0" value="2" type="checkbox"></td>

        <td>September 14, 2010</td>
        <td>Royal Festival Hall - London, United Kingdom</td>
    </tr><tr class="gradeU even">
        <td><input id="instance_selected1" name="instance_selected1" value="2" type="checkbox"></td>

        <td>September 15, 2010</td>

        <td>O2 Academy Newcastle - Newcastle Upon Tyne, United Kingdom</td>
    </tr><tr class="gradeA odd">
        <td><input id="instance_selected2" name="instance_selected2" value="2" type="checkbox"></td>

        <td>September 16, 2010</td>
        <td>Glasgow Barrowlands - Glasgow, United Kingdom</td>
    </tr><tr class="gradeU even">
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the unhiding bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution, but [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/V3P5w/) works

```
$(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').siblings().each(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

And here's how you unhide it: ([Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/V3P5w/3/))

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var check = $(this).attr('checked');
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings().each(function() {
        if (check) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }
        else {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function clickEvent(e) {
    $('#the-table tr').not($(e.target).closest('tr')).fadeOut();
}
```

This essentially says "all the `tr` tags in the table except for the first ancestor of the clicked checkbox that is a `tr`". In other words, all the other ones. Bind this function to the `click` event of the checkbox and you should be good to go. Another way to express this would be:

```
$(e.target).closest('tr').siblings().fadeOut();
```

I prefer the second way, but the first is more intuitively correct IMO.

Be warned, though, that you might have trouble animating the `tr` elements in multiple browsers...you never know what you're going to get with tables in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('tr input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  $('tr').not($(this).closest('tr')).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

[Demo on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/erowe)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
  $("tr").not($(this).parent().parent()).fadeOut()
});
```