# hiding the tr tags and showing them after the uncheck

Tags: jquery

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714242/how-do-i-fade-out-all-the-other-tr-tags-with-jquery) about 15 minutes ago and I got some good responses. But one thing i forgot is if the user unchecks the checkbox all the others that were hidden need to reappear again.... any ideas

i was using this

```
$(function() {
 $('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).hide("slow");
    });
 });
});
```

but maybe there is a better way and how do i show the others that are hidden after I uncheck the checkbox

Comment: Couldn't you have just edited this bit into that question? :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `.hide("slow")` to `.toggle("slow")`